# Relays stay "on" after Node-red deploy

Tags: node-red

I have Node-Red running on a Raspberry Pi controlling an Arduino. Connected to the Arduino is a Sansmart 16 relay board.

In my flow, in the dashboard switch, "On" payload is "false" and "Off" Payload is "True" (if I reverse the payloads then the relays turn "on" when switch is turned off).

All works fine except when I deploy a change or restart system. All relays turn on and stay on, but if I go to the dashboard and cycle the switch (on then off), the relays stay off till turned on and all works fine.

Anyone know why the initial state is "On".  Is there a way to cycle the switch (relays) at startup?

Thank you.

Here is the flow:

```
[{"id":"63d9ce70.698d","type":"function","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"C to F","func":"var tempc = msg.payload;\n    tempf = tempc * 9/5 + 32;\n    tempf = Math.round(tempf * 10) / 10;\n    //tempf = tempf.toFixed(0);\n    msg.payload = tempf;\n    return msg;\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":370,"y":500,"wires":[["6635ceea.6df41"]]},{"id":"75445653.b45628","type":"arduino out","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Relay","pin":"2","state":"OUTPUT","arduino":"91c80dfb.96132","x":330,"y":40,"wires":[]},{"id":"86df60ea.59775","type":"rpi-dht22","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Temp","topic":"rpi-dht11","dht":"11","pintype":1,"pin":"7","x":230,"y":460,"wires":[["63d9ce70.698d","d9eca468.e59af8"]]},{"id":"490dc8aa.b762c8","type":"inject","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","topic":"","payload":"true","payloadType":"bool","repeat":"5","crontab":"","once":false,"x":90,"y":460,"wires":[["86df60ea.59775"]]},{"id":"6635ceea.6df41","type":"ui_text","z":"73027f99.95023","group":"81cc84d8.1a5d78","order":1,"width":"3","height":"1","name":"","label":"Temp","format":" {{value | number:0}}&degF","layout":"row-spread","x":510,"y":500,"wires":[]},{"id":"d9eca468.e59af8","type":"ui_text","z":"73027f99.95023","group":"81cc84d8.1a5d78","order":2,"width":"3","height":"1","name":"Humidity","label":"Humidity","format":" {{value | number:0}}%","layout":"row-spread","x":520,"y":460,"wires":[]},{"id":"f9e5b087.c144d","type":"ui_switch","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","label":"Water Heater LP","group":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":false,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"false","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"true","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":130,"y":40,"wires":[["75445653.b45628"]]},{"id":"db1d317f.b8069","type":"arduino out","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Relay","pin":"3","state":"OUTPUT","arduino":"91c80dfb.96132","x":330,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"b5bcf4ea.4787b8","type":"ui_switch","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","label":"Water Heater Elec","group":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"false","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"true","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":130,"y":100,"wires":[["db1d317f.b8069"]]},{"id":"90953aa1.393028","type":"arduino out","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Relay","pin":"4","state":"OUTPUT","arduino":"91c80dfb.96132","x":330,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"e88a071d.cfd698","type":"ui_switch","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","label":"Outside Lights","group":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"false","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"true","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":120,"y":160,"wires":[["90953aa1.393028"]]},{"id":"3c899def.edc9c2","type":"arduino out","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Relay","pin":"5","state":"OUTPUT","arduino":"91c80dfb.96132","x":330,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"fe2b8790.43aa88","type":"ui_switch","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","label":"Inside Lights","group":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"false","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"true","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":110,"y":220,"wires":[["3c899def.edc9c2"]]},{"id":"7e323c7a.93d234","type":"arduino out","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"Relay","pin":"6","state":"OUTPUT","arduino":"91c80dfb.96132","x":330,"y":280,"wires":[]},{"id":"5f7afe49.02c31","type":"ui_switch","z":"73027f99.95023","name":"","label":"Water Pump","group":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"","style":"","onvalue":"false","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"true","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":110,"y":280,"wires":[["7e323c7a.93d234"]]},{"id":"91c80dfb.96132","type":"arduino-board","z":"","device":"/dev/ttyACM0"},{"id":"81cc84d8.1a5d78","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Temp","tab":"b070480d.c92ec8","disp":true,"width":"3"},{"id":"4ebcec92.a5bd34","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Switch Board","tab":"b070480d.c92ec8","order":2,"disp":true,"width":"6"},{"id":"b070480d.c92ec8","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Command Center","icon":"dashboard"}]
```

Comment: Thxs hardillb.  Seems the problem is that during reboot or deploy, the Arduino pulls all the pins low which, on this relay board, energizes the relays. And the pins stay low until I cycle the switch in the dashboard, setting the pin to high (de-energizing the relays).  Is it possible to place a node that cycles the switches or forces the pins High once on startup?  I've tried inject (set to send False once at start up) - Switch-Relay, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The dashboard ui switches do not send messages with their initial state on start up or redeploy.

If you want to send a message on start up then you should use the inject node with the appropriate settings